# Tikz: Drawing an S-shaped line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm creating a presentation using the beamer class, and I'm having issues trying to create an S-shaped arrow.  Specifically, I have the following so far:

```
\documentclass[compress,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external,decorations,arrows,shapes,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \scalebox{0.9}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm,>=stealth',auto]
        \tikzstyle{llnode}= [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=4,draw=black!50,inner sep=0mm,
            text width=5mm, minimum height=5mm,rectangle split horizontal=true,
            align=center]
        \node[llnode] (node2) [node distance=2.5cm]
             {8\nodepart{two}11\nodepart{three}$\top$\nodepart{four}15};
        \node[llnode,fill=red!75] (node3) [right of=node2,node distance=2.5cm]
             {25\nodepart{two}26\nodepart{three}29\nodepart{four}28};
        \node[llnode] (node4) [right of=node3,node distance=2.5cm]
             {65\nodepart{two}82\nodepart{three}67\nodepart{four}78};
            \draw[->,color=black] (node3) -- (node4);             
        \node[below of=node2,node distance=10mm] (prev) {$prev$}
            edge[->] (node2);                                 
        \node[below of=node3,node distance=10mm] (curr) {$curr$}
            edge[->] (node3);  
        \node[llnode] (node3a) [above of=node2,node distance=1.5cm]
            {25\nodepart{two}26\nodepart{three}$\top$\nodepart{four}$\top$};
            \draw[->,color=black] (node2.east) -- (node3a.west);              
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

This produces the attached output.

[image: Output].

What I want to do is create an S-shaped arrow that exits node2.east and enters node3a.west.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
\draw[->,color=black,rounded corners=2mm] (node2.east) -| ++(3mm,8mm) -|
                 ([xshift=-3mm]node3a.west) -- (node3a.west);
```

[image]