# Tikz: Making S shaped arrows to avoid nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to make an S shaped arrow to avoid the nodes in my diagram. I can put a corner in but don't know how to have more than 1. I have tried to follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215185/tikz-drawing-an-s-shaped-line) but can't get it to compile with my code.[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows, calc}


\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {Camera};
\node (Transmitter) [process, right =of start] {Transmitter};

\node (Receiver) [process, below =of start, yshift = -2cm] {Receiver};
\node (Computer) [process, right =of Receiver] {Computer};

\node (Field) [process, below =of $(start)!0.5!(Transmitter)$] {Field};



\draw [arrow] (start) -- (Transmitter);
\draw [dotted] (Transmitter) |- (Receiver);

\draw [arrow] (Receiver) -- (Computer);
\draw[arrow]  (Field) -> node[left]{}($(start)!0.5!(Transmitter)$); 


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

I have just used the `|-` and `-|` connectors together with a point part way between the `start` and `Computer` nodes. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows, calc}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {Camera};
\node (Transmitter) [process, right =of start] {Transmitter};

\node (Receiver) [process, below =of start, yshift = -2cm] {Receiver};
\node (Computer) [process, right =of Receiver] {Computer};

\node (Field) [process, below =of $(start)!0.5!(Transmitter)$] {Field};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (Transmitter);
%\draw [dotted] (Transmitter) |- (Receiver);

\draw [arrow] (Receiver) -- (Computer);
\draw[arrow]  (Field) -> node[left]{}($(start)!0.5!(Transmitter)$);
\draw[rounded corners, arrow] 
    (Receiver.north) |- ($ (start)!0.7!(Computer) $)
                      -| (Transmitter.south);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a great answer, but is it possible to position the bend to be in the middle of a node instead of trying to work out where the middle is relative to the whole picture?

Comment: @JonnoBourne You could add an "empty" node somewhere and then draw the arrow through there.

Comment: So if I want the bend to be under the middle of the Transmitter node I make another node underneath it and draw the arrow through it?

Comment: Yes, that's one way. There was another solution posted (and deleted) by @Torbjørn T. that used relative coordinates: `\draw [dotted,rounded corners=10] (Transmitter) -- ++(0,-2.5) -| (Receiver);`. Perhaps this would work better for you?